# Merge VS code menu bar to Ubuntu(Unity) default top bar

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

In the last update, I got a new menu bar. I use the default Ubuntu menu bar which is just one row on the top. How can I get that back?

[image]

Is there a way to get rid of this menu bar and merge it back to the top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should select `Window: Title Bar Style -> native`

Set this in your settings file

```
"window.titleBarStyle": "native"
```